# why does my x axis ticks are not sorted properly in plotly graph

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot a sales trend, over the weeks. But in the x axis, the ticks are not in proper sorted order, there by making my graph look weird.

Graph : 
[image]

As you can see , the circled week , needs to come in starting or the axis. Why does this happen like this even after I have sorted the dates in the dataframe ?

Pandas Code :

```
basic_df = filterDataFrameByDate(df,start_date,end_date)
df = basic_df.groupby(['S2PName',basic_df['S2BillDate'].dt.to_period(flag)], sort=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum'),('count','size')]).reset_index()
df.sort_values('S2BillDate',inplace=True)
df['S2BillDate'] = df['S2BillDate'].astype('str')
```

Also one more thing that I notices is, when i de-select 'Samosa' from the legends , the ticks are arranged properly.

Screenshot:
[image]

Can anybody help me out with this please ?

Pandas Code and data :

Code :

```
 print(df['S2BillDate'].unique())
```

OP :

```
    <PeriodArray>
['2020-02-03/2020-02-09', '2020-02-10/2020-02-16', '2020-02-17/2020-02-23',
 '2020-02-24/2020-03-01']
Length: 4, dtype: period[W-SUN]
```

Code :

```
   df = basic_df.groupby(['S2PName',basic_df['S2BillDate'].dt.to_period(flag)], sort=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum'),('count','size')]).reset_index()
```

OP :

```
[537 rows x 4 columns]
                          S2PName             S2BillDate   totSale  count
0                          SAMOSA  2020-02-10/2020-02-16   4057.89    228
1                          COFFEE  2020-02-10/2020-02-16  10567.21    582
2                             TEA  2020-02-10/2020-02-16   6808.92    445
3                           POORI  2020-02-10/2020-02-16   7556.77    179
4                          PONGAL  2020-02-10/2020-02-16   4758.97    122
..                            ...                    ...       ...    ...
411                PEPPER CHICKEN  2020-02-24/2020-03-01     90.00      1
412  SEZWAN CHICKEN FRIED NOODLES  2020-02-24/2020-03-01    199.50      2
413         SEZWAN VEG FRIED RICE  2020-02-24/2020-03-01     69.83      1
414         SEZWAN EGG FRIED RICE  2020-02-24/2020-03-01     89.78      1
415                    EGG MASALA  2020-02-24/2020-03-01     50.04      1
```

Comment: Do you mind to share a sample of  your data? I guess that one of the culprit is the dtype for dates.

Comment: Hi , I have updated the question with the data. In case further more details are reqd pls do let me know, happy to share. This bug is driving me crazy for days

Comment: In your data there is a date only for S2PName-Categor in this way I don't think I can reproduce a line plot. Then you should consider to use the standard pandas notation for weekly aggregate series. That is date `2020-02-09` is considering all period `2020-02-03/2020-02-09`

Comment: No that was just a sample , let me pull out the exact  code and OP

Comment: Now I have for every item, in the updated OP of my DF

Comment: @rpanai Pls let me know if the above details makes sense !

Comment: Could you produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) for coffee and samosa only with the 4 weeks of February?

Comment: Sure! But I ll have to break my df and do that, will be be okay if I can reproduce using jupyter notebook and share it via github link ?

Comment: It's ok to me. But in order to have something useful for the comuuniity it will be great to have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem. I'm using `plotly.express` but it works in the same way with `plotly.graph_objs`

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"SPName":["SAMOSA"]*3+ ["COFFEE"]*4,
                   "S2BillDate":["2020-02-10/2020-02-16",
                                 "2020-02-17/2020-02-23",
                                 "2020-02-24/2020-03-01",
                                 "2020-02-24/2020-03-01",
                                 "2020-02-17/2020-02-23",
                                 "2020-02-10/2020-02-16",
                                 "2020-02-03/2020-02-09"],
                    "totSale":[4000, 4500, 5000, 10_000, 12_000, 10_000, 2000]})
```

This produce

```py
fig = px.line(df, x="S2BillDate", y="totSale", color="SPName")
fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Here the problem is how dates are sorted. If you see the first point for `COFFEE` is `2020-02-24/2020-03-01` the second `2020-02-17/2020-02-23` ans so on.

A quick fix will be

```py
df1 = df.sort_values("S2BillDate").reset_index(drop=True)

fig = px.line(df1, x="S2BillDate", y="totSale", color="SPName")
fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
```

[image]

I personally prefer to work with dates rather than strings on `xaxis`

````py
df["Date"] = df["S2BillDate"].str.split("/").str[1].astype("M8")
fig = px.line(df, x="Date", y="totSale", color="SPName")
fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
```[![enter image description here][3]][3]

but in this case in order to show the ticktext in the format you asked for you still need to sort `df` and in this case there you need more coding.

```python
df = df.sort_values(["Date"]).reset_index(drop=True)
fig = px.line(df, x="Date", y="totSale", color="SPName")
fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        type="category",
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df["Date"].tolist(),
        ticktext = df["S2BillDate"].tolist()
    )
)
fig.show()
````

Comment: I cannot thank you enough sir ! I was stuck for days. I really really appreciate the time and effort u took to help me out. Thanks a ton !